# Angular 2 Font to server

Tags: html, angular, sass

I have a problem with the font on the server. Localhost works, but the server has a different directory and does not read. With Logo is the same.

```
@font-face 
font-family: BankGothic;
src: url('/assets/fonts/BankGothic.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('/assets/fonts/BankGothic.woff') format("woff"), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
url('/assets/fonts/BankGothic.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
```

The logo is made as a component
Is it possible to integrate this font and logo?

Comment: Just place it where it belongs on the server.

Comment: The link is different and can be changed, is it possible to otherwise link it?

Comment: try `../assets/fonts...` if your `font-face` code lives in `app.scss`

Answer (score 1):

Try using absolute path for linking your font.
e.g

```
@font-face 
font-family: BankGothic;
src: url('http://www.example.com/assets/fonts/BankGothic.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('http://www.example.com/assets/fonts/BankGothic.woff') format("woff"), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
url('http://www.example.com/assets/fonts/BankGothic.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
```

Maybe it helps you out. But if it's working on your localhost than it should be working on your server also. Unless and until you are following different directory structure on server. But this is obvious that your issue is regarding src path

Comment: Good idea etc but more have to combine in the build

Answer (score 0):

I thought maybe something with

```
environment.apiUrl
```

But I do not know if it has the right to do it